# no ethernet and no wireless working

Tags: networking

I tried to install Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS on my new notebook but the installation failed saying `stopping mount network filesystem`.

So I tried with Linux Mint 13 mate 64bit, and the installation succeeded, even if neither ethernet nor wireless connection was working during install.

After installing everything is fine except that I neither have ethernet nor wireless connection at all. The network manager reports `No network devices detected`.

**Specifications:**

- Acer Aspire E-522- 65204G1TMnkk
- Processor is a 4x AMD A6-5200 APU
- Radeon (TM) HD Graphics, 4gb RAM.

The output of `lspci -nn`:

```
01:00.0 Ethernet Controller (0200): Atheros Communications Inc. Device (1969:10a1] (rev 13)
05:00.0 Network Controller (0280]: Atheros Communications Inc. Device (168c:0036] (rev 01)
```

Any suggestion to fix this problem?

Here I am with the results of the commands:
- ifconfig:
lo Link encap:Local Loopback inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0 inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:16436 Metric:1 RX packets:28 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 TX packets:28 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 RX bytes:1920 (1.9 KB) TX bytes:1920 (1.9 KB)

- sudo dhclient eth0:
  Cannot find device "eth0"

Update 12 february:

I found the solution, both for the ethernet card and the wireless adapter, but the problem is that they do not work together. 
Doing:

"Download compat-drivers source code https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/2013/03/04/compat-drivers-2013-03-04-u.tar.bz2

Extract the tarball and type the following commands on a terminal:

cd [path-to-extracted-driver]
./scripts/driver-select alx
make
sudo make install
Reboot the system"

the ethernet connection worked well. But still no wireless.

After that, I followed these suggestions for the wireless adapter:

"sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential
wget http://www.orbit-lab.org/kernel/compat-wireless-3-stable/v3.6/compat-wireless-3.6.6-1-snpc.tar.bz2
tar xvf compat*
cd compat-wireless-3.6.6-1-snpc
sudo su
./scripts/driver-select ath9k
make
make install
modprobe ath9k
exit"

Even if the last command "modprobe ath9k" didn't work, I rebooted and I had the wireless working BUT .... no more ethernet again!!!

Is there anybody who can tell me how to solve this?

Comment: What is the output of the "ifconfig" command?

What if you run "sudo dhclient eth0"?

Comment: here I am with the results of the commands you suggested: ifconfig

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:28 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:28 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1920 (1.9 KB)  TX bytes:1920 (1.9 KB)


sudo dhclient eth0

Cannot find device "eth0"

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are owner a device with chip ath9k: http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/ath9k

There are several ways to handle the problem, for example turning off a hardware encryption:

http://www.emmolution.org/?p=253

Comment: Ok thanks: I went to http://www.emmolution.org/?p=253 and followed instructions: sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf

adding

options ath9k nohwcrypt=1   but I now have a terminal open with this line added in it and I cant understand how to save and exit...

Comment: I tryed the solution of turning off hardware encription but it did'nt work at all. No change in wireless. And I also have problem with ethernet. The network manager still reports: NO NETWORK DEVICES AVAILABLE..